# Can't get object out of array for display

Tags: javascript, html, lunrjs

I'm trying to build a simple search interface for a dataset that I have created.

I have followed the Lunr [guides](https://lunrjs.com/guides/getting_started.html) to create an index.  I put an input box on my webpage that gets the search value typed by the user, then runs that value against the index.

When I run `console.log(results[0])` - I happily get the right result in my console:

[image: screenshot of a line from the console: object {ref: "Legal & Legislation Compliance", score:1.2, matchData: {..}]

The problem comes when I try to get "legal and legislation compliance" to show up on my webpage.  Two things happen:

When I try to output `console.log(results[0].ref)` to the console, the program freezes and I can't type anymore.

When I try to output `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= results[0]` to the webpage I get [object object] - which is surprising because the console line gives the actual data associated to the object.

```js
var documents = [{
    "TooltipInfo": "administration - administration general: 2 years 5 years de: ",
    "Category": "None1",
  },
  {
    "TooltipInfo": "administration - appointment books, diaries, desk calendars: 1 years 0 years de: ",
    "Category": "None2",
  },
  {
    "TooltipInfo": "administration - correspondance day files: 1 years 0 years de: ",
    "Category": "None3",
  },
  {
    "TooltipInfo": "legislation and directives - general: 2 years 0 years de: ",
    "Category": "Legal & Legislative Compliance",
  }
]

var idx = lunr(function() {
  this.ref('Category')
  this.field('TooltipInfo')

  documents.forEach(function(doc) {
    this.add(doc)
  }, this)
})



var searchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input')
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var results = idx.search(searchInput.value)
  // console.log(results[0].ref)

  // var results2 = results.forEach(function(item){return item})
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results[0]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lunr/lunr.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

How do I get the search result to show up on my webpage?

Comment: You should use .`.ref` since you store your value in `ref` try `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results[0].ref`

Comment: appreciate your help!  that doesn't work for me though.  when I add results[0].ref, it gives an error code.

Comment: On second thought you were right Hakan - I upvoted the answer that had your solution.  Apologies for the early morning brain malfunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a value for `innerHTML`. Here `results[0]` is a object. So this should be `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results[0].ref`

```js
var documents = [{
    "TooltipInfo": "administration - administration general: 2 years 5 years de: ",
    "Category": "None1",
  },
  {
    "TooltipInfo": "administration - appointment books, diaries, desk calendars: 1 years 0 years de: ",
    "Category": "None2",
  },
  {
    "TooltipInfo": "administration - correspondance day files: 1 years 0 years de: ",
    "Category": "None3",
  },
  {
    "TooltipInfo": "legislation and directives - general: 2 years 0 years de: ",
    "Category": "Legal & Legislative Compliance",
  }
]

var idx = lunr(function() {
  this.ref('Category')
  this.field('TooltipInfo')

  documents.forEach(function(doc) {
    this.add(doc)
  }, this)
})



var searchInput = document.querySelector('#search-input')
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var results = idx.search(searchInput.value)
  //console.log(results[0])

  // var results2 = results.forEach(function(item){return item})
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results[0].ref;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lunr/lunr.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for your offer of help!  I tried adding `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results[0].ref;` but as you can see from your code snippet, it returns an error

Comment: if the value is between 0 to 2 then there is no error as you have 3 values in your list

Comment: You are right!  apologies, I hadn't opened the code snippet in the full window.  Many, many thanks.

Comment: I also figured out that my debugger was "pausing on exceptions" - so it wouldn't let me complete the typing.  thanks again for your help.